# Moving Content That's Been Stolen

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I have several articles on a website that I would like to move to my own domain.

However, some of the content I have written has been stolen by other sites. I have filed a lot of paperwork with hosting companies, Google, etc, to have it taken down, but it still exists on websites hosted in countries that don't respect copyright.

How do I move content to a new domain and let Google know, "Hey, this is mine, don't penalize it."

Unfortunately, the website it's currently on is not my domain, so I have no ability to redirect it or add anything to the header.

**Updated:** Old question, but I have been afraid to move the content. I'm hoping that, with time, a solution now exists.

Comment: 301 Permanent Redirect from your current place to a new domain.

Comment: Content is on a site whose CMS does not allow users to add a 301 redirect. (HubPages.)

Answer (score 11):

If you can modify the `<head>` at hubpages, add a canonical link to your new domain.

```
  <head>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.newdomain.com/article_name.html"/>
</head>
```

Good related post: [Using rel=canonical with syndication](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3658/using-rel-canonical-with-syndication)

Answer (score 0):

Do i get this right? You published something on HubPages and now you complain that other people republish it? ಠ_ಠ

from the [Terms of Use](http://hubpages.com/help/user_agreement):

> By posting Hub Content on the Service, You grant HubPages a ...
>   license ... to reproduce, publicly display, publicly perform,
>   distribute, modify, adapt and publish the Hub Content.  ... By posting
>   Author Content on the Service, You grant HubPages a worldwide,
>   royalty-free, non-exclusive, perpetual, irrevocable license to
>   reproduce, publicly display, publicly perform, distribute, modify,
>   adapt and publish the Author Content on or in connection with the
>   Service...

I could imagine that a lot of automated spam tools scrape content form such article database to feed their own splogs, since the articles there are easy to scrape, nicely organized and get a lot of fresh content.

*Captain Hindsight says:* If you didn't want your articles getting scraped and republished by spambots, you should have never published it on any article website.

Comment: The Terms of Use you cited represents an agreement between the individual and Hubpages, not the individual and spammers. One could just as easily say "If you didn't want your articles getting scraped and republished by spambots, you should have never published it on the internet." - and that says far more about the spambots than the author of the content.

Comment: Sure, but the point i was trying to make here was that it nowhere states that your published articles stay your "exclusive property", and people will always copy your photos, articles and other work you upload to the internet - no matter if it is allowed or not by laws or terms of use.

Comment: I maintain the copyright of the content under their TOS.